# Sprite Mask option doesn't appear

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a Sprite Mask object. I follow the instructions on the unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html):

> To create a Sprite Mask select from the main menu GameObject > 2D Object > Sprite Mask

But the only option that appears is "Sprite". I am using the latest version of Unity (5.6.3p2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an earlier version of Unity, 5.6 is quite old.
Here is the link https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

Comment: All this time I thought I had the latest version because clicking "check for updates" said that this was the latest version. I feel so stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

A Sprite Mask object is nothing but a gameobject with a **SpriteMask** script attached to it.
So create a empty game object and add a **SpriteMask** component to it through inspector manually